# Hiding JSON field that Client sees

Tags: json, spring, mongodb, rest, jackson

I am implementing a web app where users enter their personal information to store them onto a database, in this case MongoDB. This acts much like an address book. These services are implemented using a REST API (I am using Spring framework), where clients can call GET requests to view other people's personal information, POST to add their own information, and PUT to update. The Administrator of the DB can use DELETE To remove users.

I have implemented all the CRUD operations for the services on the server side. But I have one question:

When a client calls GET for a particular user to see his information, the request is returned as a JSON string, where the password field is visible. I do not want the client to see the password, obviously.

Now, I tried adding `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"password"})` at the top of my model class on the server side. Although this works and the client cannot see the password, **The password is also not even stored on the MongoDB database with this implementation**. Because when I call db.users.find().pretty(), to list all the documents in the collection, I do not see the "password" field for any of the users.

I need some way for the password to be stored on the DB, but unable to be viewed by the client.

Here is one of the GET methods which finds a user by his username:

```
/* Get user by username */
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/getByUsername")
    public @ResponseBody User getUserByUsername(@RequestParam("username") String username) {
        return repo.findByUsername(username);
    }
```

The Model class is just a class with a bunch of String variables, and getters and setters.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the retrievedFields method available in Morphia.

```
getDs().createQuery(className)
       .field("username").equal(username)
       .retrievedFields(false, "password")
       .get();
```